# How can I find a word in a C# string

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I need to load a long string from the internet and I have done that. Now I need to find the `H1` header tag and print the contents.

What is the shortest or the easiest way to do that?

```
for (int x = 0; x < tempString.Length; x++)
{

    if (write == 2)
    {
        name =name + tempString[x];
        lenght++;
    }
    if (tempString[x] == '<' && tempString[x] == 'h' && tempString[x] == '1' )
        write = 1;

    if (write == 1 && tempString[x] == '>')
        write = 2;

    if (tempString[x] == '-' && write == 1)
        write = 0;
}
```

I know it's a bit how shall I say odd. But it's all I have.

Comment: thnx for all of your help but atm i can't tell who gave the best answer because i got a 404 error on the server conenction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) - Pretty much anything else you try is just going to cause you a [headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

**HtmlAgility sample:**

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body><h1>hello</h1></body></html>";

HtmlDocument d = new HtmlDocument();
d.LoadHtml(html);

var h1Contents = d.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1").InnerText;
```

Comment: Well, not *anything* else, but most things people try will.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Added the obligatory answer as to why Regex doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in flat C#, and you're only looking at 1  tag:

```
int first_tag = str.IndexOf("<H1>");
int last_tag = str.IndexOf("</H1>");
string text = str.SubString((first_tag + 4), (last_tag - first_tag));
```

Comment: you might need some offsets to your substring call. otherwise it will contain the <h1> txt.

Comment: Thanks. Added + 4 (the length of the <h1> tag)

Comment: what happens when that heading tag has a class assigned to it?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I completely understand, and for that instance you would require a few more checks, but I don't think that is what OP requires. If OP requires this information, I'm sure we can work it out :D

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML library!

Otherwise try:

```
String.IndexOf(String x )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

you can use that to get the first index of the  start and end tags. you can then just read between those indices.

Answer (score 1):

The System.String class has methods like **IndexOf(String)** - Reports the zero-based index of the first occurence of the specified string.

So in your case, you could pass in `"<H1>"`. Then you could get a substring starting at that point, and then call this method again looking for `"</H1>"` again.

Or if you want, it might be easier to use Regular Expressions in .NET. Those are found in the System.Tet.RegularExpressions namespace. Those are definitely more complicated. But I'm sure you could practice using some small samples and learn the power of the dark side! (errr....) the power of regular expressions! :)

[edit] Now that I see other's answers, I definitely agree with others. If you need do anything more complicated than getting one item in an HTML formatted string use an html parser.

Answer (score 0):

all of the above work fine i just can't use any external libaries

this works well for me

```
for (int x = 0; x < tempString.Length; x++)
        {

            if (tempString[x] == '-' && write == 2)
            { write = 0; }

            if (write == 2)
            {
                title =title + tempString[x];
                lenght++; 
            }
            if (tempString[x] == '<' && tempString[x+1] == 'h' && tempString[x+2] == '1' )
            { write = 1; }

            if (write == 1 && tempString[x] == '>')
            { write = 2; }


        }
```

Comment: indexof is not an external library. You have basically the same code as what you say has been rejected by your college three times. Have you asked your professor WHY it's been rejected 3x?

Comment: yes pure stupidity first time there were no language tags witch i don't nead because it's all in elnglish. the second time i parsed the link title instead of the paragraph title the only difference is that sometimes there is an upacse insdead of a low one